# Maximise total profit

Tags: algorithm

Suppose the price of car fluctuates each day, but on any single day the price is always the same. Suppose One person buy when the price was low and sell them when the price was high.

But for each day only one of following operations are allowed.

```
Buy one car.
Sale all cars that he owns
Do nothing
```

Whats the maximum amount that can be obtained?

EXAMPLE : Say we have N(=3) days and the cost of car on each of 3 day is {1,3,70} where C[i] represents cost on ith day.Then the maximum amount that can be obtained in this case would be 136

Explanation : He can buy one car on the first two days, and sell both of them on the third day.

How to find maximum amount ?

Comment: 1,3,70 known at starting time? Min and max car prices known?

Comment: What's the price on the fourth day? What have you done so far? Maybe this is also a math question and you want to post it over there? edit: huseyin tugrul buyukisik, I think it means day 1: cost for a car 1, day 2: cost for a car 3, day 3: cost 70. So buy 1 for 1, 1 for 3 (now we have -4) sell all on day 3 (2*70-4=136) and "Do Nothing" on day 4.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I misread your question, huseyin.

From what you have here it's fairly easy: sell everytime before the price drops, and buy on the other days.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths not programming.

Comment: is asking about an algorithmic problem off topic? I dont think this is off topic.

Comment: @SebastianHöffner sorry i edited my question.It was typo error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let Price[k] be car price at day #k

```
maxP = -inf
for k = last_day downto first_day 
  P = Price[k]
  if P < maxP then
    Action[k] = "Buy one car"
  else
    maxP = P
    Action[k] = "Sale all cars that he owns"
  end if
end for
carsOwned = 0
sumEarned = 0
for k = first_day to last_day
  P = Price[k]
  if Action[k] == "Buy one car" then
    carsOwned += 1
    sumEarned -= P
  else
    sumEarned += P*carsOwned
    carsOwned = 0
  end if
end for
print(sumEarned)
```

This solution requires O(n) memory and O(n) time.

Comment: what if the array is sorted ascending? you will sell every day?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Did you get the question right?I want maximum amount of money.

Comment: @user3306991 - Sorry, forgot to calculate the sum.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I think this is still not what is demanded in question.Could u please explain ur algo by an example?What happen if two consecutive days have max price.I think it shld be handle sepratly

Comment: @user3306991 - You can play with my algo here: [1,3,70](https://eval.in/104709), [90 every day](https://eval.in/104708).  Just change first line of code and click "Submit" button.

Comment: @user3306991 - Probably, "sell 0 cars" would better be changed to "Do nothing", but in fact it is the same action :-)

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with the obvious - if you  know the day that the price is maximal(the index of the maximal value in your array of car price per day), Its fairly obvious that the optimal action up until that day would be to buy a car every day and sell them all on that maximal day.

So, one algorithm to solve this would be to find the maximum, calculate the profit in the sub array [0:index_of_max] of buying a car every day and selling at the max, and reiterate this process for the remaining array. Time complexity would be O(n^2).

Comment: What if their are more than one maximum?Let if their are two maximum positions i & j then u mean to buy from 0 to i-1 then sell at i then again buy at i+1 to j-1 and sell at j and what about after that?Do nothing..Is this what u wanna say?

Comment: If you would start with an array of days sorted by price, you could get the time complexity down to O(n*log(n)).

Comment: @nwellnhof Could u please explain your algorithm.I didnt get you

Comment: @WeaselFox Is it O(n^2) or O(2*n)?If it is O(n^2) then how is it?Could u please provide some pseudocode or so?

Comment: @user3306991 Nevermind, Egor Skriptunoff just posted an O(n) solution.

Comment: @nwellnhof -  yes, sorted this could be O(nlogn). good call

Comment: @user3306991 - sorry, no time, I`m at work..